# Create a 3d shaped button in android

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles

I was trying to create a button similar in look to the round buttons over here -

http://livetools.uiparade.com/index.html

(every button looks like it is inside an immersed section) I had it by placing the button 
in a circle background and giving them both a little gradient that didnt end up the same 
though I got this result - 
[image]

(I will upload my code once I can) how can I achieve that same look?

Comment: A friendly reminder ([because they still haven't got round to implementing automatic closure notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/308440)): this question got closed (months ago). Can you improve it to make it valid?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this code. I am able to produce an image that looks like this

[image: Android xml button]

which is similar to the first button you link to, using the following code. The key is to use `<layer-list>` to layer shapes one over the other to produce the desired effect.

**File: res/drawable/button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <!-- Outside border/shadow -->
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <size android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp" />
      <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#f4f4f4" android:endColor="#b9b9b9" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- Inset -->
  <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
      <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#dcdcdc" android:endColor="#c9c9c9" />
      </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- Inside border/shadow -->
  <item android:top="15dp" android:left="15dp" android:right="15dp" android:bottom="15dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#8c8c8c" android:endColor="#cbcbcb" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- Main button -->
  <item android:top="16dp" android:left="16dp" android:right="16dp" android:bottom="16dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <!-- Button image -->
  <item android:top="70dp" android:left="70dp" android:right="70dp" android:bottom="70dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#3b88c2" />
      <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:top="75dp" android:left="75dp" android:right="75dp" android:bottom="75dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
      <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:top="80dp" android:left="80dp" android:right="80dp" android:bottom="80dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#3b88c2" />
      <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

In your main layout, add an `ImageView` that will display this image.

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/button" />
```

You can make the `ImageView` clickable by giving it an `OnClickListener` in the Java code.

Comment: You just got yourself 50 points right there sir..! =)

Comment: Good Example brother. But I have one question. how to give content padding with this shape ? because text within button touches the border.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I'm not sure where you are adding text -- As far as I know an `ImageView` cannot hold text. If you change the `ImageView` to a `Button`, and set `android:background="@drawable/button"`, any text you set in `android:text` will be centered. You can also try setting the `android:padding` attribute of the `ImageView`/`Button`

Answer (score 6):

Go to this link and Generate Custom 3D button.

http://angrytools.com/android/button/

**buttonshape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="30dp"
/>
<gradient
android:gradientRadius="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerY="50%"
android:startColor="##4CAB0B"
android:endColor="#004507"
android:type="radial"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#0B8717"
/>
</shape>
```

**Button Code**

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/angry_btn"

android:text="Button"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30sp"

android:layout_width="270dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
android:shadowDx="3"
android:shadowDy="2"
android:shadowRadius="8"
/>
```

Comment: Wow! Marvellous!! 7 years later and that link still works!!!