# How to use 9-patch images to create a 3-D like button(the one that looks elevated) or is there any other way

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying from two days,to get a button that looks 3D,like the buttons in the **candy crush**(not animation part,jus the look and feel). I want to do it programmatically not using XML.Here is wat i have tried so far.Is there any other way to get a button in the above description.

```
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.orange);
    byte[] chunk = bitmap.getNinePatchChunk();
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.set(0, 0, 0, 0);

    NinePatchDrawable npd = new NinePatchDrawable(getResources(), bitmap, chunk, rect, null);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    npd.draw(canvas);
```

[The name of the image file is orange.9.png :i generated the 9 patch using this [link to the tool](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

[image: orange.9.png]

Comment: show me your 3D button image

Comment: i have posted it...i'm placing this button(orange.9.png) in onclick of another button..there is no error or no exception...but i can see nothing on the screen..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218407/create-a-3d-shaped-button-in-android 
 this will help you for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can create drawables xml shapes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/bgColor"
        android:startColor="@color/bgColorDark" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/fgColor" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

There are more elements you can add but this will give you a rounded corner shape with gradian and stroke :)

Edit:

If you only want to do this with a 9-patch image then you just need to make the corner of your image round.

Comment: i tried this for my other applications using xml...it works fine but it misses the 3D effect what i expect...But as of now i'm creating an API to place most of the views dynamically where in now i wanted give 3D effects for the buttons which i place it dynamically when users call my display routine .I'm able to place the above 9 patch image on the screen,but not in 3d format..thanks

Comment: can u help me how to set corner radii for 9 patch drawable image programatically??

Comment: The gradian colors can give you the 3d effect if you use them right you can also add android:centerColor="@color/"

Comment: No bro i want in java code, user of my class will pass me background color for the button he wants to use. And i have add shadow and color at the same time using java code and not xml.

Comment: Well now i'm not using 9 patch instead just create a button dynamically and round up the corners,set the user provided background color, and later adding shadow to the same. This is my thought process. But i dono how to achieve all this together.